# how to select subdocuments from mongodb and store it in an array, then display it?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

my database structure

```
{
"Author_Name" : "mukund",
"Quote_Details" : [
    {
        "Quote_Text" : "Lost in the woods",
        "Quote_Catagory" : "Something",
        "Quote_Time" : "systime",
        "Occassion" : "some time",
        "Said_TO" : "somebody"
    },
    {
        "Quote_Text" : "Miles to go before i sleep",
        "Quote_Catagory" : "Nothing",
        "Quote_Time" : "besttime",
        "Occassion" : "i dont know",
        "Said_TO" : "Nobody"
    }
],
"_id" : ObjectId("535f6dc8b8082fd3f80dea0f")
}
```

My php code

```
$query = $collection->find(array("Quote_Details.Quote_Text" => new MongoRegex("/^$q/i"),"Author_Name" => "$author"));

$json2 = array();
   foreach($query as $result) 
        {  
            //echo $result['Quote']."\n" ;  
             $json2[]= array('val'=>$result["Author_Name"],
                'value'=>$result["Quote_Details.Quote_Text"]);
        }
        echo json_encode($json2);
```

i think it is working, coz when i am getting a value as null for only 'value' in text box when i input correct values. i am getting correct author names when provide q as "Lost in the woods" and author_name as "mukund", but in the place of 'value' it is shown as null

one more thing to note is that if i put any other value for q, as needed not output is obtained

the console output is

```
[{"val":"mukund","value":null}]
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem with your code is you are still trying to use the JSON notation for accessing the inner document when you actually need to be using the PHP notation. Since your PHP notation doesn't match anything you get the null result.

But really, this is not what you want to do as you are post processing the results in code. You could have done this server side very easily:

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
  array(
    '$match' => array(
      'Quote_Details.Quote_Text' => MongoRegex("/^$q/i"),
      'Author_Name' => "$author"
    )
  ),
  array(
    '$unwind' => '$Quote_Details'
  ),
  array(
    '$project' => array(
      '_id' => 0,
      'val' => '$Author_Name',
      'value' => '$Quote_Details.Quote_Text'
    )
  )
));

echo json_encode( $result['result'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) . "\n";
```

So now, as shown, you don't need to iterate the results anymore as you can just encode on the spot and you have re-shaped to exactly what you want in the result.

Comment: @Mukund feel free to vote that up (if you didn't already) since you have the privilege level to do so. :)

Comment: there is a small problem, the idea is to print 'Quote_text' as autocomplete, its not working completly, if i give either m or l, the list is populating all, and if i give anyother letter the list is not populating at all, as it should be. i mean Quote_Text  starting with L and M are populating and they need to filer as autocomplete

Comment: @Mukund Sorry I must have misread your intent and actually wrote it this way by design. You you actually want only the array members that match? If so repeat the $match stage after the unwind. And I do mean **repeat** it as you want to have it there twice. If you need a further example of this then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, your collection is multidimensional (documents and subdocuments).
So, you may get the "value" in result with below code :

instead of using :

```
$result["Quote_Details.Quote_Text"]
```

In the foreach loop

use this instead :

```
$result["Quote_Details"]["Quote_Text"]
```

Above code gives you output as :

```
[{"val":"mukund","value":"Lost in the woods"}]
```